# Echo multiple variables to dzen bar

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that has three functions.  Each has an output that I pipe to dzen2.  Below is a pseudo-code version of the script.

```
printVol()
{
LEVEL=getVolume
VOL='Volume: '$LEVEL
echo $VOL
}

printBattery()
{
LEVEL=getBat
BAT='Battery: '$LEVEL
echo $BAT
}

printDate()
{
DTE=getDTE
echo $DTE
}

#this is the line I need to figure out
printVol | dzen2 -x 900 && printBat | dzen2 -w 150 && printDate | dzen2
```

The goal is to print each of these to the dzen bar.  Individually, each dzen call works.  How do I send all of the values to the dzen bar at the same time?

EDIT: I have three different dzen calls because each echo needs to be positioned specifically on the dzen bar.  -x and -w are positioning flags.

Answer (score 1):

Use a command group:

```
{ printVol; printBat; printDate; } | dzen2 -x 900 -w 150
```

I'm assuming that it makes sense to aggregate all the options into a single call to `dzen`.

Comment: The primary issue I'm having is that I need each echo to be positioned in a specific part of the dzen bar.  -x and -w are positioning flags.  I don't think grouping them would fix that.

Comment: So you have three different inputs and three different destinations. I'm not seeing how you picture combining them.

Comment: I've seen examples of multiple variables being sent to a dzen bar with the position of variable being set.  I'm just not sure this is done.  I can't find a way to position specific arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `dzen` -- I assume from your example that it reads text from stdin. So in bash, use [process substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
dzen2 -x 900 < <(printVol)  
dzen2 -w 150 < <(printBat) 
dzen2        < <(printDate)
```

If you need to pass the text as a parameter instead, simple command substitution will do:

```
dzen2 -x 900 "$(printVol)"  
dzen2 -w 150 "$(printBat)"  
dzen2        "$(printDate)"
```